# Delete till first occurrence of colon using sed

Tags: sed

My sed command is,

```
 sed '/(.*:)/d' <<< 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf'
```

It must return,

```
bcde:cdeaf
```

(i.e.) all characters before the first colon in the line and the colon itself must be removed.

But this is not removing anything.

My confusion arises mainly due to,

1) Does parens for pattern matching need to be escaped inside sed regex-es?

2) In either case(with escaping/no escpaing), it is nt working.
I tried,

```
sed -E '/\\(.*:\\)/d' <<< 'abcd:bcde'
```

Comment: you want `sed 's/[^:]*://'`. And you're not `d`eleting the input line, by the way, you're modifying it with a `s///`ubstitution command. You have to replace the first not colon bit and the colon that follows it with nothing at all.

Comment: that solves it... thanks, man... this is an example i took to learn regex pattern matching inside sed... so, i am looking for an answer that uses group/pattern match with parens...

Comment: Or, just using bash: `printf "%s\n" "${line#*:}"`...

Comment: @jasonwryan - good point, considering the example source. it's definitely the more efficient way to handle it. but if it's a `while read line` that gets the `$line`, probably `sed` should be preferred.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `d` command in `sed` deletes a whole line.  What you want to use here is an `s` (substitution) command.

```
$ echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | sed 's/[^:]*://'
bcde:cdeaf
```

The `[^:]` is how to write "not a colon".  The `*` after the not-a-colon expression means "any number of the things right before me" (in this case, the not-colon).  Finally, the `:` selects a colon.

Matches always happen from left to right in a greedy fashion, so this is guaranteed to match the first part of the given string, up to and including the first colon.

In other words, select any number of things that aren't a colon and the first colon.

The `//` means to replace the matched substring with nothing (i.e. delete it).

Answer (score 4):

To operate with columns there is `cut`:

```
echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | cut -d: -f2-
```

same do

```
echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | cut -d: -f1 --complement
```

And other version with `sed` (more quick for big data):

```
echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | sed 's/^://;t;s/:/\n:/;D'
```

And rather exotic in `bash`

```
echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | { IFS=: read -r first last ; echo "$last" ; }
```

or

```
echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | { read -r line ; echo ${line#*:} ; }
```

or

```
echo 'abcd:bcde:cdeaf' | { IFS=: read -a a ; printf '%b:' "${a[@]:1}\c" ; echo ;}
```

Comment: You could also add the proper way to do it with sed, that is `sed 's/[^:]*://'`

Comment: @don_crissti The version is noted in the answer above. Additionally due to *regexp* use it is slower as have to compile expression in each line.

Comment: No, it's not. The answer above sucks big time and deserves lots of downvotes - especially if you read the revisions and the comments there.

Comment: @don_crissti instead of being salty in the comments on multiple answers, why not just post your own answer with the better code? I would upvote it because as you say it's a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Gostega -  this is an over-five-years old story but OK... there are proper ways to do it as mentioned in the comments under the question, either via shell per _jasonwryan_ or with `sed` + regex as _mikeserv_ explained - he also edited that in the accepted answer but the OP decided to [rollback the edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/232658/revisions) along with a "brilliant" reply to the editor...  Two years later, I guess I was just passing by and asked Costas to include Mike's comment in his post which is something we used to do back in the day when we were active here...

Comment: @Gostega - anyway, feel free to turn it into an answer if you think it's worth it, it's no big deal as far as I'm concerned, it's been beaten to death - by that I mean stuff like "how to remove 1st field" or "how to delete till 1st occurrence of something" or "how to print all after 1st occurrence"  (which are pretty much the same thing...). I'll upvote your post and even add some solutions that weren't mentioned here :)